# @AutoImplement groovy failing

Tags: groovy

I am trying to use the @AutoImplement annotation for generating the default implementation of an interface
as outlined in below example

https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2018/06/groovy-goodness-implement-interface-and.html

Below is my code

```
public interface SomeInterfaceGroovy {
    Integer anotherDumbMethod()
}


import groovy.transform.AutoImplement
@AutoImplement
public class SomeImpl implements SomeInterfaceGroovy {
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        def some = new SomeImpl();
        some.anotherDumbMethod()
    }
}
```

but i am getting null pointer exception

On Debugging i found that the metaclass is always null and below is the stacktrace

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at com.ambuj.risk.xcoll.Main.main(Main.groovy:6)
```

Any idea what could be the solution

Answer (score 0):

got it working by implementing GroovyInterceptable

Comment: Would you mind fleshing this answer out a little bit?  I assume you added it to `SomeImpl`?